# Drag UIImageView images using UITouch Methods

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I have a UITableViewCell with UIImageViews embedded. I understand it's not common practice but I'm using the UITouch methods to accomplish horizontal swipes. I retrieve images from a url/api . The issue is I wish to drag one image at a time from either left to right. The problem is, when i drag my finger on across the imageView, all loaded images slide through quickly. I want to focus on one image at a time during the drag. Hope I was clear.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
  startLocation = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
  CGPoint point = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
  UITouch * touch = [touches anyObject];
  self.viewOne.center = CGPointMake(self.viewOne.center.x+point.x - startLocation.x, self.viewOne.center.y);

if (startLocation.x < point.x) {
    //Swipe Right
    if ([self.photo.photoURLS isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
        if (self.isSwiping == NO) {
            self.isSwiping = YES;

            self.currentImage--;
            if (self.currentImage == -1) {
                self.currentImage = 12;
            }

            self.viewBack.frame = CGRectMake(-self.frame.size.width,0.0f, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);
            self.viewBack.hidden = NO;

            self.loadingImage.hidden = NO;
            NSURL *imageURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:self.photo.photoURLS[self.currentImage]];
                [self asyncLoadImageFromURL:imageURL andPhotoID:self.photo.id withCallback:^(UIImage *image, NSString *photoID) {

                    self.loadingImage.hidden = YES;
                    [imageCache setImage:image forKey:self.photo.photoURLS[self.currentImage]];
                    self.viewBack.image = image;

                    //new
                        self.viewOne.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);
                        self.viewOne.image = self.viewBack.image;

                        self.isSwiping = NO;
                        self.pageControl.currentPage = self.currentImage;
                        self.viewBack.hidden = YES;

                }];

            }
        }
    }


} else {
    //Swipe Left
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you're asking or what the issue is, but the following lines are suspect:

```
CGPoint point = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.vehicleImage];
self.viewOne.center = CGPointMake(self.viewOne.center.x+point.x -startLocation.x, self.viewOne.center.y);

if (startLocation.x < endLocation.x)
```

You are not setting `endLocation` until after you've finished touching the screen. During your `touchesMoved` responder, you'll be using bad `endLocation` data. You should be using the value of `point` in this function to determine motion.

It's also not really clear what is the relationship between `self.vehicleImage` and `self.viewOne`. If `self.vehicleImage` is a subview of `self.viewOne` (or otherwise moves during your frame changes), your `locationInView` will return seemingly inconsistent values, exaggerating the motion of your finger. Instead, you should be picking a view that will stay static during this process (perhaps your ViewController's `self.view`).

Comment: my mistake, viewOne is indeed the same as self.vehicleImage. I used 'if(startLocation.x < endLocation.x)' to differentiate between dragging left and right. The issue is when I drag my finger either left or right, the loaded images change quickly but I want to focus on one image when I drag my finger across the screen. the AirBnB app is an example.

Comment: You can't use `endLocation` for this purpose, though. You are setting it in `touchesEnded` which is always called *after* all your `touchesMoved`.

Comment: thanks again :), I've updated the code but as you mentioned, the exaggerating the motion of the finger persists. I wish to drag one image at a time from either left-right or right-left

Comment: Stop using the `locationInView:self.vehicleImage`. You need to always only fetch the location relative to another view in order to get consistent motion. Use `point` instead of `movedLocation`.

Comment: Do you have something specific that you're asking now about your code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71695/discussion-between-drpatience-and-ian-macdonald).